# mysql performance on custom newsfeed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, database-design

I've developed a forum for bodybuilding, where users can ask questions and get answers. So the questions are all in onepage, and by clicking "load more" at the end of the side, you get 10 more questions with ajax (something like facebook newsfeed / startpage).

the database design is very relational.

i have a table "questions" a table `questionanswers`, a table `questionlikes` and a table `user`

So when the questions are displayed, there is only the `username, questionpreview, question, title and likes count` (very similar to Facebook status)

The Problem is, i think my program is very low-performance (when i click "load more" it takes up to 8 seconds to load the new questions via ajax), because i join everything. i join for counting the "likes" i join for finding out the "username" i join for counting the "answers" etc.

So i wanted to ask you, wouldn't the database be more efficiently, if i made something like a "reader" table where everything about the question is hard coded, instead of joining everything?

sorry for my very bad English!

Comment: You are most likely missing some indices. Post output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE xxx;` for all tables.

Comment: hello @EugenRieck now i added on every "foreign key" an index. i think my database is now like 100 times faster. is this possible??